# Reading a .txt with scores from a soccer season file then printing another with team records

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that reads a file "soccer.txt" that has the following information:

### Heading ## soccer.txt:

```
Lions Panthers Tigers Sky
Panthers    4   Tigers      3
Tigers      3   Lions       1
Sky         2   Panthers    0
Lions       2   Tigers      1
Tigers      1   Sky         6
Sky         2   Panthers    1
Tigers      1   Sky         4
Panthers    3   Tigers      6
Lions       3   Sky         2
Tigers      4   Sky         3
Sky         2   Panthers    1
Lions       4   Panthers    6
```

Then outputs a .txt file:

### Heading ## results.txt:

```
Team        Wins        Losses
Lions       2            2
Panthers    2            4  
Sky         5            2
Tigers      3            4
```

I have started writing the code for this. And am trying to test it, but I cant get the program to reccognize that the .txt file exists even though I have the "soccer.txt" file saved to the desktop.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Soccer
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    //initiate an input file object and scanner object
    File inData = new File("soccer.txt");
    if(!inData.exists())
    {
      System.out.println("File does not exist");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inData);

    //create output file and a printWriter object
    File outData = new File("results.text");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outData);


    String teamName1 = input.next();
    String teamName2 = input.next();
    String teamName3 = input.next();
    String teamName4 = input.next();

    output.println(teamName1);
    output.println(teamName2);
    output.println(teamName3);
    output.println(teamName4);

    input.close();
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's saved to the desktop, your `new File("");` should contain the correct, absolute file path. (right click on your .txt and select properties: under Details, what is the file path you see?)

The `("soccer.txt")` relative path assumes the file is in the root folder of your project

Comment: you need to start your program from desktop, or maybe an easier solution, put absolute path

Comment: move this file to your src folder

Comment: Thank you! I have moved the program and .txt file into the same folder. With the code i have now i am getting an output with the four team names.

Comment: After making some fixes the program no outputs a file. However, I'm not sure how to go about determining each team's win/loss record.

Comment: @A.334 - then ask a new ***specific*** question about the win/loss determination, including what you have tried / are trying so far. A general question such as _"How do I determine the win/loss record"_ will not do well. See the SO help center [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)